Android Back Button closes my Flutter app
The error occurs with auto_route: ^9.2.2
Previously auto_route: ^5.0.3 was used and everything worked fine.
I am using AutoTabsScaffold() for routing and what happens now is that when the back button is pressed in android the application closes, which did not happen before.
this is an example of how I have the routes in my app
    AutoRoute(
                  path: 'a',
                  page: A.page,
                  children: [
                    AutoRoute(
                      initial: true,
                      page: B.page,
                    ),
                    AutoRoute(
                      page: C.page,
                    ),
                    AutoRoute(
                      page: D.page,
                    ),
              
                    AutoRoute(
                      page: E.page,
                    ),
                    AutoRoute(
                      page: F.page,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),



AutoTabsScaffold(
                routes: [
                  B(),
                  C(),
                  D(),
                  E(),
                  F(),
                ],
                bottomNavigationBuilder: (_, tabsRouter) {
                  return BottomNavigationBar(...);
                }, `enter code here`
              ),

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.22631.3880], locale es-419)
    • Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at C:\Users\Liam\dev\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2663184aa7 (7 weeks ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
    • Engine revision 36335019a8
    • Dart version 3.5.3
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Liam\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)

[√] VS Code (version 1.94.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Liam\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.96.0

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

I have already tried adding PopScope() in the App() component and also in each individual widget but this does not prevent the app from closing.
I also tried putting android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback=“false” and nothing.

I found that if I change class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() instead of class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {}
The navigation works PERFECT. The problem is that I need my app to use FlutterFragmentActivity since I'm using STRIPE.
This is a solution that is working for me for now is to create custom onNavigationNotification in MaterialApp.router constructor.
bool _defaultOnNavigationNotification(NavigationNotification _) {
  switch (WidgetsBinding.instance.lifecycleState) {
    case null:
    case AppLifecycleState.detached:
    case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
    // Avoid updating the engine when the app isn't ready.
      return true;
    case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
    case AppLifecycleState.hidden:
    case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      SystemNavigator.setFrameworkHandlesBack(true); /// This must be `true` instead of `notification.canHandlePop`, otherwise application closes on back gesture.
      return true;
  }
}

And then:
MaterialApp.router(
  onNavigationNotification: _defaultOnNavigationNotification,
);

